# How to tell the difference of the path of OnRestoreInstanceState?

Tags: android, onrestoreinstancestate

I have somewhat problem with coping with `OnSaveInstanceState`/`OnRestoreInstanceState` pair. It is said it is for temporary saving of the state, the best example is when phone is rotated. This part works great for me.

However `OnSaveInstanceState` is called also when application simply quits. Several hours later I start app (from my perspective it is a new run), and to my surprise Android calls `OnRestoreInstanceState` and is able to dig out "old" values of the state.

This ruins my logic because my current code assumes this pair is called only when apps runs constantly (from user perspective), so in the second scenario half of my app behaves like it was just started (correct), while other half behaves like it is in the middle of processing some data (because it got such values from the preserved state; which is not intended).

Of course I could hack it and ditch this pair altogether and use global values in app instance, but I wonder how to do it correctly/gently without using big guns?

**Update**: important events that happen:

- first run of my app
- screen was rotated or not
- my app goes through OnPause or whatever, the crucial point is it goes through `OnSaveInstanceState`
- some time passes
- I run the app again, in logs I see the **application** constructor is called (as I understand it everything is created fresh new)
- within new app instance activity OnCreate/OnResume/etc is called
- and among those `OnRestoreInstanceState` is called too, and its bundle instance is not null -- it means the temporary state instance crossed **application** (not just activity) lifespan (this worries me)

*Gingerbread 2.3.*

*For the time being I ended up using global variables stored in application, because it is recreated on each launch, yet preserved on screen rotation it behaves as I would expect it.*

Comment: Your app is not killed if the user presses the home button. So no wonder it keeps state if it comes to the front again. You can kill your app using the back button on your activity.

Comment: @blackapps, thank you, this is always good to know. But maybe I put too much emphasis on quitting, so I put it in another perspective -- when I see the application constructor is called I would say this application is created from scratch and for me it is really unexpected that activity within this new application instance is able to dig up the old instance state from previous run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Several hours later I start app (from my perspective it is a new run), and to my surprise Android calls OnRestoreInstanceState and is able to dig out "old" values of the state.

On modern versions of Android, the saved instance state is only around for ~30 minutes, not several hours. However, that still may be after your process has been terminated while your app is in the background, to free up system RAM.

> I wonder how to do it correctly/gently without using big guns?

Only use the saved instance state `Bundle` for the process-termination scenario.

For configuration changes, if you were working on modern versions of Android, you would use a `ViewModel`. Your "Gingerbread 2.3" suggests that you are into retrocomputing, and few current libraries exist that will support such an old OS version. For a pure Android SDK solution for API Level 10, you would use `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()` and `getLastNonConfigurationInstance()`. `ViewModel` is built (indirectly) on top of those methods.

Comment: In my last case it was 4 hours. The problem is not in timespan, but behaviour. When users quits app it is rather expected the data is gone, so when the app is executed again it won't start in the middle of the last run. "Only use the saved instance state Bundle for the process-termination scenario." I use only the bundles provided OnXXXInstanceState because they were supposed to be used in such scenarios as screen rotation. So I assumed Android know the reason and call this pair only in such case.

Comment: @greenoldman: "When users quits app" -- I do not know what you mean by "quits app". Pressing HOME, for example, is closer to minimizing a window in a desktop OS. "I assumed Android know the reason and call this pair only in such case" -- you are welcome to do so if you wish. In general, your app needs to be able to handle both starting from planned entry points (e.g., launcher activity) and arbitrary other spots. For example, if you have `static` objects that only get set up properly when the app starts from the launcher, that's a bug that you will need to fix.

Comment: Thank you for explanation. As for various spots, I fully agree and this is way I try to understand the workflow of Android. I simply understood that when I see application (not activity) constructor is called I can say it is a "barrier" -- what was in the past it is in the past. Yet, Android passes data from old **app** instance (more accurately -- activity within old app) and passes it to new one (through InstanceState pair mechanism).

Comment: @greenoldman: Yes, that's working as intended. The idea is that the user should be given the illusion that the device has infinite memory, when it does not. And so the user should be taken to where they were last, rather than coming back "through the front door". Google toned that back a bit to 30 minutes, but the idea remains the same.